# Using Oxford Speech API in unity

Tags: api, azure, speech-to-text, unity-game-engine, azure-api-apps

I want to integrate the oxford speech recognition API in a project in unity. 
The problem is that the source code in the sample use .NET 4 libraries while unity only support until 3.5 (and only until .NET 2 on phones as far as i know)
Did someone found a way to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code you mention is the SDK sample I believe. The functions that come with the SDK is just wrappers around the actual REST API requests. You don't necessarily need to use them. Instead I suggest you give the REST API itself a try. You can find the info below.

https://www.projectoxford.ai/speech

And [here](https://oxfordportal.blob.core.windows.net/speech/doc/recognition/Program.cs) is sample usage for your convenience

[API testing](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797/console) console.

One more thing to remember is the Auth token expires every 10 mins so it's a good idea to renew every 9 mins.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i didn't want to mess with implenting a wrapper to REST but it looks like the only option. For now i did a prototype of what i want in Android, maybe i will take the time to switch back to unity.. I mark it as an answer and will take a look at this sample, thanks anyway!

Comment: From what i understand, the rest api doesnt support partial result so no way to use it for live speech recognition.

Comment: Hi Haim, its actually got renamed to Microsoft Cognitive Services. It does support partial recognition and real time sources. You can find it here https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api

Comment: hey @neolursa good to know, i didnt knew the name was changed!  [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/overview) is a quote from the documentation:
"Using the REST API means getting only one reco result back with no partial results." 
what i understand from that - no real live recognition, i need to send audio parts and wait for results?

Comment: for anyone interested, it looks like unity is investing in this direction: in the new beta version (5.4), they added [DictationRecognizer](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.html) wich is a class that provide speech recognition